# Download large file from Databricks DBFS with Python API

Tags: python, api, download, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to download some large files from Databricks storage using their DBFS API but i'm only getting a portion of the file under 1 MB (single API call size restriction).

There is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/examples#---upload-a-big-file-into-dbfs) of large file upload which uses session with a handle. I assume I would need something like that but I can't wrap my head around it.

The [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs#--read) functionality doesn't have a handle but has `offset` argument. I assume I could make a loop with incremental offset to pull 1 MB per call but it doesn't sound like an optimal solution. Moreover, when I try to do that I still get files ~520 KB of size.

Answer (score 0):

> **Scenario 1**

Using databricks portal you can directly download up to  (1 milion rows)
[image: Ref1]

> **Scenario 2**

Install azure [databricks cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/) and configure with azure databricks .Use this command `dbfs  cp <file_to_download> <local_filename>` and download file.
You can use DBFS API- 2.0 with unix command line [interface CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--databricks-cli)

Reference:  [Access DBFS with azure databricks.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#access-dbfs)

> **Scenario 3**

Direcltly download DBFS  files with Web URL

**Sample Final URL:**

```
  https://adb-87xxxxxxxxx.9.azuredatabricks.net/files/tables/dd.csv/?o=8xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response but it's not what i'm trying to do. I would like to be able to download the file with Python API so the download functionality could be a part of a web app